# Decrypting a substitution cipher text file in C

Tags: c, encryption

I got a problem that asks to decrypt a text file. The encryption scheme used to encrypt this message is a substitution cipher. The message file is called: **substitution_cipher_enc_message.txt**, and the keyfile is: **subst_dec_keyfile.txt**.

The way the keyfile works is, byte 0 of the keyfile is what the ASCII character 0 maps to, byte 1 of the keyfile is what ASCII character 2 maps to, etc. There are 128 bytes in this keyfile, and I  need to read them all into your program in order to decrypt. A suggested take is to read in the encrypted message and encounter the ASCII character 28, then the plaintext mapping of that character is byte 28 of the keyfile, but I have no idea how to do that.

What I have so far is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main() {
 
 FILE *MessagePointer;
 char fileName[] = "substitution_cipher_enc_message.txt";

 MessagePointer = fopen(fileName, "r");

 if (MessagePointer == NULL) {
   printf("Error opening file %s\n", fileName);
   exit(1); //non zero exit
 }

  int maxChars =  1000;
  char decryptmsg[maxChars + 1];

  fgets(decryptmsg, maxChars, MessagePointer);

  fclose(MessagePointer);

//before decrypt
  printf("\nFile: %s\n\nYour message reads:\n %s\n", fileName, decryptmsg);


FILE *keyPointer;
 char keyFile[] = "subst_dec_keyfile.txt";

 keyPointer = fopen(keyFile, "r");

 if (keyPointer == NULL) {
   printf("Error opening file %s\n", keyFile);
   exit(1); //non zero exit
 }

  char keytxt[maxChars + 1];

  fgets(keytxt, maxChars, MessagePointer);

  fclose(keyPointer);
//keyfile
  printf("\nFile: %s\n\nYour keyfile reads:\n %s\n", keyFile, keytxt);




  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to explain yourself more precise. How shall the encryption work exactly? What is your problem?

Comment: The encryption of say `encryptmsg[i]` would be `keytxt[ encryptmsg[i] ]` assuming that the input is in the expected range 0..127. It is a lookup table. The snag is, though, if the key file contains a newline, the `fgets()` which reads it will stop there. You need to read the key file with `fread(keytext, 1, 128, keyPointer);` You'll also need to make a decoding lookup table from the first one (or search the first one for every value).